# Create an "pressed in" look

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon

I'm trying to recreate a fairly common look, but I really like how it is executed on getpebble.com

The getpebble.com icons are on the left, and my disaster of an attempt is on the right. As much as I try, I've wasted close to 3 hours of my life and I am still left with a hideous looking icon for my personal project. Any pointers?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like they just use an inner shadow:

[image]

Here's what that produces (original on the left, my attempt on the right):

[image]

Comment: How'd you get the colors of the icons to look exactly the same. I tried to use the eyedropper tool to get the dark grey color inside the watch, but when I applied it to my refresh button, it didn't look perfect (like yours).

Comment: I used Color Overlay layer style, with #E2E2E2 set as the Color. Your Eyedropper tool may have a sample size that is too large, to check select the tool and look at the top toolbar. "Sample Size" should be set to "Point Sample"

Comment: Sorry, but why "Color Overlay"? Why not eyedropper and then paint bucket? EDIT: I used "Color Overlay" with that color and it looks perfect. You are awesome! But, please answer that question lol. Thanks!

Comment: I almost never use the Paint Bucket tool. I use either Color Overlay or Fill (from the Edit menu); they're more precise when flooding a layer or a selection with a color. It's mostly a work-flow preference, though. It's what I'm used to doing

Comment: Gotcha. Good to know. I appreciate all of your time.